# How to get json from external url with port?

Tags: c#, json

I want to get json string from external url with proxy.

What setting  i need to set to take access to the url with proxy?

here my example code:

```
        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        Response.Write(myWebClient.DownloadString(@"http://www.otherwebsite.com:11111/json.aspx"));
```

then i receive an error enable connect to remote server but if i remove the proxy it can access  and return json to me.

Any information provide to me?

Comment: `http://www.otherwebsite.com:80/json.aspx`  :)

Comment: What port do you want to use for access?

Answer (score 1):

You got valid response after removing port number in URL. This indicates web server is listening to port 80 and not port number 11111